# UIButton like Rating bar that i want to do anyone help me?

Tags: ios, uibutton

i want to use button is in either way

i want to use if user select one time button then its display different color after that click on button it appear as usual after click it display that color

```
static int tapCount = 0;

- (IBAction)BtnClickdemo:(id)sender
{

    tapCount++;

    if (tapCount == 1)
        [btnClick setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"line.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    else if (tapCount == 0)
        [btnClick setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MinSelected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    else
    {
        [btnClick setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MinSelected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

User only select 2 tappded like Ratingbar taped ??

How can i do ??

Comment: Please try to rephrase your question. I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a `BOOL` value to your button and check this value everytime the button is tapped:

```
@implementation youCustomViewController {
    BOOL buttonSelectionned;
    UIButton *myButton;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    /* Init objects */
    buttonSelectionned = NO;

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    myButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
    myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MinSelected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

and then implement your method `buttonTapped`

```
- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
    if (buttonSelectionned) {
        buttonSelectionned = NO;
        myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MinSelected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        buttonSelectionned = YES;
        myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MinSelected2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }  
}
```